# Ubuntu 22.04 with Qt6 - qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

Tags: apt, 22.04, qt, qmake

In Ubuntu 22.04 after installing **Qt6** using

```
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
```

calling `qmake` results in an error message:

```
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

or

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

It is however possible to call/run `qmake6`. How to make `qmake` work and point it to `qmake6`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Ubuntu 22.04 there is currently an open bug [QtChooser doesnt support
qt6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtchooser/+bug/1964763).

So even if Qt6 has been installed using `sudo apt install qt6-base-dev`, `qtchooser -l` does not list a
qt6 option and `qmake` outputs `qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''`.

Assuming Qt6 is installed and `qmake6` can be called, I believe there are two options:

**1. Select Qt6 system-wide**

Generate `qt6.conf` based on the path to `qmake6`

```
qtchooser -install qt6 $(which qmake6)
```

Move `qt6.conf` to system-wide dir

```
sudo mv ~/.config/qtchooser/qt6.conf /usr/share/qtchooser/qt6.conf
```

Set Qt6 as default option

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/$(uname -p)-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser
sudo ln -n /usr/share/qtchooser/qt6.conf /usr/lib/$(uname -p)-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf
```

**2. Select Qt6 for current user only**

Generate `qt6.conf` based on path to `qmake6`

```
qtchooser -install qt6 $(which qmake6)
```

Select Qt6 as default (place in `~/.bashrc` for persistence):

```
export QT_SELECT=qt6
```

Comment: If you run `qtchooser -install` as root (eg, use `sudo`), it will add the configuration to the `qt-default` directory instead of a user's home directory, removing the need to move the conf file. This also means, for the purposes of creating a Docker image (as I am), you only need to do step 2 in the Dockerfile (that is `RUN` the command and set the `ENV` variable) for it to be functional container-wide.